# xml multilevel parsing based on id using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am working on a web app GUI, where user will select value from a drop down and based on that selection other drop-downs will be updated. I want a scalable solution because there exists a lot of combinations so I want to implement it using xml. earlier I worked with single level xml files, Here I have to get values based on multiple dropdowns, My xml file is like below:

```
<code_gen>
<met id = "1" name="NTPV">
 <sment id="1">
    <name>FLAG</name>
    <filename id="1">POS.txt</filename>
 </sment>
 <sment id="2"> 
    <name>On_Off</name>
    <filename id="1">on_off.txt</filename>
 </sment>   
 <sment id="3"> 
    <name>Seller</name>
    <filename id="1">seller_e2e.txt</filename>
</sment>        
 <sment id="4">
    <name>Border</name>
    <filename id="1">cross.txt</filename>   
</sment>    
 <sment id="5">
    <name>NA_Segment</name> 
    <filename id="1">NA_e2e.txt</filename>  
</sment>    
</met>
<met >
....
</met>
</code_gen>
```

I want to access segment names and filenames based on selection of met. I am able to access list of met but unable to list inner details using concept of childNodes[].nodeValue.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can access any particular element this way by changing the values for childNodes[], if it helps.

```
 xmlObj.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```